# How to use bash file in centos crontab

Tags: php, bash, cron, centos

i want to run 50 php page from crontab every minute what is the best way 
insert every one in crontab or use bash to load all from one corn 
this is example what i need

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/folder/page.php?id=1
1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/folder/page.php?id=2
1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/folder/page.php?id=3
etc ...
```

so can me use query link like this `?id=1` in crontab or bash file

Thanks

Comment: I think you should look at the design of the system

Comment: why add bash in to the mix, you could do it all with php

Comment: As we do not know how long the script takes to run it might end up with lots of processes on the system. consider it the script takes 2/3 seconds to run, each iteration will still be running when the new iteration via cron is starting. Not much good for system performance in the long term. You will get a back log

Answer (score 2):

You probably should look for an alternative to running 50 scripts per minute, every minute.  As [Ed Heal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal) points out, there is likely a much better way to design the system to do whatever it is that you are trying to do.

For what its worth, here is a single bash script that runs those 50 commands in sequence:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}
do
    /usr/bin/php "/var/www/folder/page.php?id=$i"
done
```

Alternatively, to run those 50 processes in parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}
do
    echo "/usr/bin/php '/var/www/folder/page.php?id=$i'"
done | parallel
```

This requires that you have GNU parallel installed.  For information on how to optimize `parallel` for your system and requirements, see [man parallel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel)

Comment: How about running those scripts in parallel?

Comment: @EdHeal GNU parallel is an excellent suggestion.  Answer updated to add parallel example.

Comment: @Ed Heal 
Hi  EdHeal To this moment I have not done anything if there is a possibility to help me in this I will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version of John1024's GNU Parallel example:

```
parallel /usr/bin/php /var/www/folder/page.php?id={} ::: {1..50}
```